# How can I accelerate the ripening of bananas?

Tags: food

The supermarket only had very green bananas, and I would like to use them in a banana bread recipe ASAP. For this recipe, I typically use bananas that are very ripe (usually spotted) like this:

[image]

How can I accelerate the time it takes for the bananas to ripen? I have tried separating the bananas from their common stem, but that only marginally increases the ripening speed.

Comment: What recipes would you like to use them for?  Appropriate techniques will vary if targeting banana bread compared to banana split.

Answer (score 13):

**Method 1 :** ***Placing them in warm area***

1. Place and cover the bananas inside packet or bowl of rice. Or
2. Expose the bananas to sunlight.

**Method 2 :** ***Exposing to ethylene gas***

1. Place them in oven with lowest possible temperature. It will emit ethylene gas and it will accelerate the ripen process. This method usually carried out during making banana bread.(do not crowd them, Air has to circulate)
2. Place the bananas inside a plastic bag.To be more fast, put a tomato or other fruit inside the bag. It emits more ethylene gas while ripening.

Comment: IIRC, apples are also quite good for Method 2.2.

Answer (score 9):

Store them in a paper bag. They will all emit [ethylene gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene#Ethylene_as_a_plant_hormone) as they ripen. Trapped inside the bag, the gas will accelerate the ripening process as it cannot escape.

Comment: Can you expand on this at all? It's very short. See: http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/82/do-answers-need-explanations-does-the-answerer-need-to-know-why-it-works

Comment: I think it's adequately explained as-is.  If someone reading it wants to know what ethylene gas is and how it works, they can easily find that information.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods I know for decelerating the pace at which they become bad once ripe

1. Separate them from each other
2. Wrap their stems with plastic

On accelerating

1. You can wrap it in a tight material, could be paper or the stuff thats used more commonly in the place where I live is dry banana leaves
2. Once wrapped it is generally a practice to light Incense sticks (basically to make smoke but not to spoil it)
3. Place this entire thing in a room with little to no air circulation